# how to use Python program from github on widows

Tags: python

After I downloaded the program [mbtilesToPngs](https://github.com/alfanhui/mbtilesToPngs) and installing Python3  I tried to convert .py file to .exe as it mentioned in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4) which I thought the way to use it but when I tray to open .exe file nothing happened just a black window like cmd that appears for a moment and disappears so how I can use it
also  I tried to open it with IDLE 3.9 and run it so I get this window (The attached photo[IDLE Shell 3.9.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inJsT.png))   .Please simplify your reply because I have no experience in python...thanks

Comment: The referenced tool requires command line arguments. How are you adding arguments to your .exe call?

Comment: The screenshot shows the output if you call the program without the mandatory option *-i*. You have to provide a path to the file. Did you read the *How to use* section on github?

Comment: yah exactly please how to provide the path

Comment: Please read [ask]. The information you are looking for is provided in the documentation of the tool. Nobody but you knows the path to your file.

Comment: finally I get it so tankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it to `.exe`, just run the `.py` file.

Comment: yah I tried to run it with IDLE  but  I didn't know what to do with IDLE Shell window or how to provide my .mbtiles file and get it as .png file

Comment: don't run it with IDLE, run it through command line, that way you can also use arguments, like Michael Szczesny suggested suggested

Comment: so thankful I just learned how to use command line to run python files